# How to map a List of child classes while having the @Element annotation's column in the parent class?

Tags: inheritance, orm, jdo, datanucleus

I have an class with 2 different `List`s. Each `List` uses a different class as it's generic type. These classes share the same base class. When I try to persist my class that contains both lists I get an error explaining that the column specified in the `@Eelement` annotation doesn't exist in each of the child classes. But this column exists in the parent class. So how can I tell datanucleus that this column is in the parent class and not the child classes ?

Base class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "Z")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
public abstract class Z {
    @Persistent(primaryKey = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

Child classes

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "X")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
public class X extends Z {

@PersistenceCapable(table = "Y")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
public class Y extends Z {
```

The class I'm trying to persist:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "MyClass")
public class MyClass {
    @Persistent(column = "id", primaryKey = "true", valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    // Specifies the FK column pointing to this object (ie. MyClass)
    @Element(column = "myclass_id")
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "list-ordering", value = "order ASC"))
    private List<X> xList;

    // Specifies the FK column pointing to this object (ie. MyClass)
    @Element(column = "myclass_id")
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "list-ordering", value = "order ASC"))
    private List<Y> yList;
```

This is part of the stacktrace I get when I try to persist `MyClass`. The whole stacktrace repeats the same information more than once for both child class tables so I just mentioned a part of the stackstrace:

```
Required columns missing from table "ipk.x" : myclass_id. Perhaps your MetaData is incorrect, or you havent enabled "datanucleus.schema.autoCreateColumns".
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.MissingColumnException: Required columns missing from table "ipk.x" : myclass_id. Perhaps your MetaData is incorrect, or you havent enabled "datanucleus.schema.autoCreateColumns".
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.validateColumns(TableImpl.java:277)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3421)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3218)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2871)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:119)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.manageClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1608)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:678)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:88)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:123)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3489)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.makePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3465)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2031)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1874)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1722)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:722)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:747)
    at ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is the `"myClass"` field in Z doing? Maybe it is supposed to be part of a **BI**-directional relation? In which case **mappedBy** is supposed to be specified at the owner side (the List(s)). Being part of a bidirectional relation is the only way you can make use of that column in Z for storing the FK for the List relation(s).

Also there is no "order" field in Z (specified as part of the List(s)) so that part wouldn't work either.

Comment: Actually having `myClass` in the `Z` class is a mistake. I removed it now. Actually the `order` and `group_id` columns are in the `Z` class's table. But the exception is about failing to find them in the base classes `X` & `Y` and the failure to create these columns too because I didn't configure Datanucleus to auto-create columns.

Comment: You mean like the message said in the first place?

Comment: So I should have it there ? I'm mapping my objects based on an existing design so I'm trying to comply with it instead of editing it which will add a lot of effort. Adding the column is an option but its my last one. Are you saying that I HAVE to have a bi-directional relation between `Z` and `MyClass` ?

Comment: You said you didnt configure DataNuceus to autocreate columns ... which is what the message in your exception tells you to do (so follow those instructions perhaps). Whether you have MyClass in Z is up to you ... is it a UNIdirectional or BIdirectional ? JDO doesn't impose that on you ... it's your model

Comment: Well I want to a uni-directional relation between `MyClass` and `Z`. And `myclass_id` column isn't located in Z's table, its in it's child classes' tables, `X` & `Y` and Datanucleus expects it to be in `Z`. Is this tunable ?

Comment: If you want it between MyClass and Z then the type of the object in MyClass List has to be Z, clearly. How else could it put it in Z if you insist on putting X or Y ?

Comment: Darn !! I confused you again. I meant I want 1-N relation between `MyClass` and `X & Y` (ie. `Z's` children)

Comment: and as I already said, if you put List of X then the FK is placed in X. Putting a FK in a supertable leads to v inefficient SQL, with the need to join, for _all_ statements relating to the List. Really got no idea what this question is *now* about. It was originally about not creating columns but you seem to be changing it

Comment: I'm sorry I confused you. My question is about how to avoid creating columns in the child tables and have the columns in the parent table only. I didn't consider joins as an issue because these tables wont hold a lot of rows and also the join must happen for Datanucleus to be able to construct the full object when the list is loaded.

Comment: I'll consider this discussion as an answer. Thank you for your time.